# Wordpress - Prevent Post Submission unless valid data

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm building a custom wordpress theme.
When the user is attempting to update a custom post type ( Product ), I want to perform some validation before letting them save/upload.

Here is what's going on.

I have a series of "Things".
Each "Thing" has an advanced custom field for img and for text.

So my goal here is, if they upload an image but don't fill in the textbox, to not allow them to save/upload the post. This also works in reverse ( if they provide text but no image ).

So right now I have hooks in 'save_post' that perform the validation and set notices at the top of the screen letting them know what they did wrong. However, this really doesn't work because 'save_post' is called AFTER the post is saved. Even if it wasn't, I still don't have any way of stopping the post from being saved anyways. The most my implementation does it let them know in hindsight that they messed up.

So, how do I accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with the `content_save_pre` filter.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/content_save_pre

Comment: I could use that filter to sanitize my data before saving it to the database. But my goal is to halt the submission alltogether if it doesn't meet my conditional logic.

Answer (score 0):

The answer ended up being to use Advanced Custom Field's provided filters.